# Should redux store enhancers (not) dispatch actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware

I have an issue where an enhancer (redux-little-router in this case) swallows an action and dispatches a new one. I also have middleware which needs to listen for this new action (along with its payload) and dispatch async actions in response.

This is impossible because the enhancer is after applyMiddleware in the chain (as it should be) and thus the new action dispatched only goes through the subsequent enhancers' dispatch functions.

This is a contrived example:

```
export const testMiddleware = store => next => action => {

  console.log('Middleware1', action.type);
  if (action.type === 'SOME_OTHER_ACTION_TYPE') {
    console.log('Hurray, responded to some other action here!');
  }
  return next(action);
};

function testEnhancer() {
  return(createStore) => (reducer, preloadedState, enhancer) => {
    const store = createStore(reducer, preloadedState, enhancer);

    const dispatch = (action) => {

      // Swallow this action, and dispatch the replacement
      if (action.type === 'SOME_ACTION_TYPE') {
        console.log('testEnhancer', action.type, 'swallowing');
        store.dispatch({
          type: 'SOME_OTHER_ACTION_TYPE',
          payload: 'some other payload'
        });
        return null;
      }

      console.log('testEnhancer', action.type, 'passing on');
      return store.dispatch(action);
    }

    return Object.assign({}, store, {dispatch});
  };
}

export default function configureStore(initialState = undefined) {
  const enhancer = compose(
    applyMiddleware(
      thunkMiddleware,
      testMiddleware
    ),
    testEnhancer(),
    DevTools.instrument()
  );
```

It seems like this is an impossible situation, but I could not find any documentation saying that enhancers should not dispatch actions. Perhaps they should not? Or are there workarounds for this?